# multi select option in iOS app - how to design the multi select button

Tags: ios, mobile-application, multi-selection, visual-cues

I'm currently working on an app that offers multi selection (see attached image). Now I am wondering how to design the multi select "circle" in the toolbar.

- **Should it be not marked while the user has not pressed it, and marked after the user pressed it?** This would be similar to checkbox behavior on a computer (as on the image left and middle).
- **Should it behave like a pause/play button which shows the pause button while playing and the play button while being paused?** Meaning: check icon in tool bar indicating that it will check all items when being pressed; and show unchecked when all items are checked, indicating that all items will be unchecked when pressing.
- **What about having used the "check all" button in the toolbar and deselecting one (or several) files manually again?** Should this affect the visual appearance of the multi select button in the toolbar?

[image: How to design feedback for multi selection on iOS]

Comment: It doesn't specifically answer your question, but in Mail, [that button is a simple text button labelled "Mark All"](http://appletoolbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/mark-all.png)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. When I did some research how other apps do that, most apps avoid the issue by using text. But as we are using a toolbar with icons that would not really work here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *play and pause* buttons is linked to audio and video files (i.e. items having a time extension) in users minds.

Given the nature of your items, you should rather use a **check-box** like representation. Your first option looks very appropriate *and nice* with the round boxes. I will take advantage of the iOS users' habits because it builds upon Apple's design (e.g. selection of several emails to move or discard them).

Regarding the "**select all**" button, you have two options whether you want to give the button a contextual impact and appearance or not :

- **going the Gmail way** : the button starts empty and changes to a tick as the user first clicks it, changes to a minus sign as some items are deselected and, when it is not empty changes its behaviour to "*delecting all*" (and the cycle starts over).
  [image]
- **keeping the tick** : starting with a ticked box and keep it that way whatever happens : the button's behaviour will then be the following : selecting all if *none* is selected, selecting all if *some are selected and some are not*, deselecting all if *all* are selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You supported my gut feeling about it, but as we had some discussion in the team I wanted to have an outside perspective on the issue! This helped a lot!

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad it helped !